# How to provide share link option of product as flipkart and amazon app provides for sharing of products link

Tags: java, android, react-native

How to provide share link option of product as flipkart and amazon app provides for sharing of products and after clicking on link my app open the same product activity in android native app.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Appflyer SDK](https://support.appsflyer.com/hc/en-us/articles/207032126-AppsFlyer-SDK-Integration-Android) you can achieve deeplinking feature.